# how to use global variable(sharable variables) in Node.js&Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a file called `data.js` for keeping data as memory database.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var aList;
var bList;
var cList;

module.exports = app;
```

And I want to initialise data when I start the server. So, I implemented `init()` in `app.js`

```
...
var data = require('./data'); // data.js is located in the same folder.

app.set(...);
app.use(...);
...

init();

...

});

fun init(){
    console.log("Hello!");

    aList = getDumpDataList(10); // I also tried with 'data.aList = getDumpDataList(10);' but didn't work.

    console.log(JSON.stringify(aList));
}

fun getDumpDataList(n){
    var list;

    ... // for loop to generate random elements.

    return list;
}

module.exports = app;
```

When I printed with `console.log()`, `Hello!` is printed but `aList` isn't printed but `undefined`

And I also want to use the data in routers under `routes` folder.

So, what I did is.

```
...
var data = require('./data');

route.get("/...", function(req, res, next){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(aList));
    ...
});
```

But it is also `undefined`.

I am just making simple test server that initialise data whenever I re-run.

How can I share variables between the js files?

Answer (score 2):

You do not export those vars:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let aList;
let bList;
let cList;

module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.aList = aList;
module.exports.bList = bList;
module.exports.cList = cList;
```

- ...but i would not put express in `data.js`, rather put it in `app.js`.
- I would also initialize those vars with initial values in `data.js`, if the initial data does not depend on something else.
- Last but not least: Do not use `var` anymore, use `let` and `const` instead. It is supported since Node 6+ (https://node.green/). I replaced it in the code.

Comment: I would add to your list of suggestions that instead exporting directly the variable _aList_, to export a function that returns its value instead making it private for anywhere importing the module.

Comment: good input, it just depends on what he wants to do with it imho. for simple things, i would not do that, to be honest. for more complex ones, functions also offer a way to parse stuff before vars get set. and maybe he does not need to change the content, then it would be a simple getter.

Comment: how to use them in routes?

Comment: just require/import them wherever you want: `const data = require('./data');` or `const {aList} = require('./data');`